# From a sum of probabilities to double integral

Tags: probability, integration, inequality, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I don't understand why, for two random variables $X\perp Y\sim Exp(\lambda)$, we have:

$$\mathbb{P}(X-w\leq Y<X)+\mathbb{P}(X<Y\leq X+w)=1-2\int_{w}^{+\infty}\left[\int_{0}^{X-w}… dy\right]dx$$

---

The passage in question is this:
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: I assumed it was because of the application of Laplace's simmetry:

$$\mathbb{P}(X-w\leq Y<X)+\mathbb{P}(X<Y\leq X+w)=2\mathbb{P}(X-w\leq Y\leq X+w)=2\mathbb{P}(0\leq Y\leq X+w)=2[\mathbb{P}(Y\leq X+w)-\mathbb{P}(Y\leq 0)]$$

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the left side as $P(X-w <Y \leq X)+P(X<Y\leq X+w)=(-w <Y-X \leq 0)+P(0<Y-X\leq w)=$

$$=P(|X-Y|\leq w)=1-P(|X-Y|> w) =1-2P(X-Y>w).$$ This can be evaluated as $1-2\int_w^{\infty} \int _0^{X-w} f_Y(y)dy f_X(x)dx$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please clarify me how you passed from $1-2\mathbb{P}(X-Y>w)$ to $1-2\int_{w}^{+\infty}[\int_{0}^{X-w}…dy]dx$? Thinking graphically it's clear that $x \in(w,+\infty)$ but I don't understand why the domain of $Y$ is $(0,X-w)$. Because for me the graph is… (see below)

Comment: @MarcoPittella $X-Y >w$ gives $Y<X-w$, so you have to integrate only up to $X-w$.

Comment: @MarcoPittella Of course, $X-Y >w$ implies $X >Y+w >w$ so the integration w.r.t. $x$ starts from $w$.

Comment: Oh, now it's clear! Really thanks Kabo Murphy!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Remains closed the little triangle in white…